# Getting a full width div into a content wrapper

Tags: html, css

I have this example layout.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
      .wrapper { 
        padding: 0; 
        min-width: 960px;
        height: 500px; 
        border: 1px solid red
      }              
      .boxed-layout .wrapper {
        width: 1000px; 
        background: #FFF; 
        margin: 0 auto; 
      } 
      .inner { 
        width: 960px; 
        position: relative; 
        margin: 0 auto; /* main width */ 
      }     
      .responsive .inner { 
        max-width: 960px; 
        width: auto; 
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="inner wrapper"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I need to add a div full width into wrapper.  So i tried this way

```css
.banner {
  position: relative; 
  left: -100px; 
  max-width: 2000px;
  width: auto; 
  border: 1px solid  green;
  height: 400px;
}
```

and

```
<div class="banner"></div>
```

but does not work well.

1. Is it correct to use relative positioning with negative left to move it to zero?
2. If I use `width: 2000px` instead of `auto`, appears the horizontal scroll bar

So, how can I have the full width and responsive?

Comment: "but does not work well."? what exactly is not working..? what is the desired output..? Where are the elements `.boxed-layout` and `..responsive` ?? without it half of the shared css won't be applied, if it's not necessary, there's no need to share it, it'll only confuse the community. Please try to make your question clear..

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right TJ. This isn't one of the best post of the community, but rohanAM gave me a way to go on

Comment: I'd like to know what's does that answer do, and how does it solve the question explained above…

Comment: @TJ My answer to this question do the work which it has to do. Please try to understand question since not every user can define porblem in greate words. But Whatever info user2741100 have provided is enough to understand user2741100's problem. The problem was that there is one 960px width container & the is a child div which needs to be 100% of body (not the parent) as per screen size. I just explained how to do that.

Comment: [well then this will be easier](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23873780/2333214)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove `position:relative` from your wrapper container (i.e. `inner` class contrainer). Then for banner use following markup:

HTML

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="banner-inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.banner {
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0;
}

.banner-inner {
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  max-width: 2000px; 
}
```

If you dont want to remove position:relative for some reason then you have to use javascript/jQuery as follows (keep markup same as above):

```
var marg = ($(window).width()-960)/2;
$('.banner').css({'left':-marg+'px','right':-marg+'px'});
```

Comment: actually what does this answer do..?

Answer (score 0):

Just give width: 100% for your div inside the wrapper. Sounds good?

Comment: .banner {position:relative; left: -100px; max-width:2000px;width:100%; height:400px;} Do not works

Comment: I am not sure if this helps you. If you need to add a inner div with fully occcupied to the size of wrapper, just bound your inner div to your wrapper. Like this <div class="wrapper"><div class="innerdiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sita met</div></div>

Comment: you dont want to specify any position to the inner div. It will automatically takes 100% of your wrapper div width.

Answer (score 0):

```
.banner { border:1px solid  green;height:400px;}
```

do not give width it's automatically take full width

Answer (score 0):

According to the accepted answer, the OP's actual problem is that there is one 960px width container & there is a child div which needs to be 100% of body (not the parent) as per screen size. This as as easy as

```
.banner {
  width: 100vw; 
}
```

*No need to change any other original properties.*

> Viewport-percentage lengths defined a length relatively to the size of viewport, that is the visible portion of the document.
>
> 1vw =1/100th of the width of the viewport

-- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length)